# The relation between the eigenspaces of $H_0$ and $H_0+H_1 $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

For the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$, we have a set of eigenfunctions $\{ f_i \}$. For the perturbed Hamiltonian $H_1$, we have another set of eigenfunctions $\{g_i \}$.

Sometimes, it is not clear to me that the $f$'s and the $g$'s span the same Hilbert space.

For example, let $H_0 = \frac{1}{2} p^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 $, and $H_1 = g \delta (x)$. It is not difficult to solve the eigenstates of $H_0+H_1$, at least numerically. But the question is, is it for sure that these eigenstates can be expanded by the harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions?

Comment: [Make mathematical sense of the Dirac well Potential Equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211701/make-mathematical-sense-of-the-dirac-well-potential-equation)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your example is flawed, because the "perturbation" you consider consists of a distribution, i.e. lies outside of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R)$. In this sense, one could formulate your problem in Hilbert space only (this is the domain of application of the famous Kato-Rellich theorem **(*)**), in which the full Hamiltonian is defined and is *under certain conditions* self-adjoint as is the non-perturbed one. In this case, both Hamiltonians have their seld-adjointness domains within the same Hilbert space.

However, since you bring in eigenvectors, then it is automatically natural to work with rigged Hilbert spaces, case in which both $H_0$ and $H_0 + H_1$ **have the same space of distributions** in which their generalized eigenvectors exist and are well-defined.

**Example**: the free particle Hamiltonian in 3D $\frac{\bf{p}^2}{2m}$ has the set of eigenvectors in the same $\left(C_0^{\infty}\left(\mathbb R^3\right)\right)'$ space as the Schroedinger H-atom (virtual particle) Hamiltonian $\frac{\bf{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{r}$. You can check for yourself that there is a particular way in which these two sets of distributions are related one to another.

**(*)** http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/14SPRINGTEA/katorellich.pdf [I hope this link won't rot over the years to come]

Comment: Regarding link rot, is that document not available in the Wayback Machine?

Comment: I don't know what the Wayback Machine is

Comment: The Wayback Machine is explained [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Wayback+Machine) ;-). It has an archived version of the Kato-Rellich notes you linked to [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20171007081350/http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/14SPRINGTEA/katorellich.pdf). In addition to that, if you want to avoid link rot, it is important that you provide an actual reference to the document (i.e. specifying its title, author, publication date, document type, and other relevant characteristics) in addition to providing a URL. If the document has moved, it's much easier to track if one knows what it is.

Comment: The $\delta$ function does not define an operator so Kato-Rellich does not apply.